# Is it possible to decrypt one-way encryption? (with real data & encrypted data)

Tags: encryption, hash, cryptography, password-encryption, hash-function

I'm Korean so English skill is very low.

I don't know encrpytion method (LIKE SHA, MD5 anything else..)

only know that this data is used one-way encryption.

I have **15,000 amounts of real data**

and have **60,000 amounts of encrypted data**

(15,000 real data is **matched** with 15,000 encrypted data)

1) real data is only numbers (length is 8 )

2) encrypted data length is 80

Is it possible to decrypt one-way encryption?

=========Here is Sample matched data============

32700130 (real data)

JDQ4MTYyMiM1MSMkMSMkNCMkOTIkMzgxMzUxIzExIyQxIyQzIyQ4OSQyNjE4MzIjNDEjJDEjJDQjJDgz

11100079

JDQ4MTg4MSM1MSMkMSMkMCMkODkkMzgxMzUxIzExIyQxIyQzIyQ3OSQzNjE4MzIjODEjJDEjJDYjJDgz

11100443

JDQ4MTg4MSM1MSMkMSMkMCMkODkkMzgxMzUxIzExIyQxIyQzIyQ2MiQzNjE0ODEjNTEjJDEjJDYjJDgz

11100494

JDQ4MTg4MSM1MSMkMSMkMCMkODkkMzgxMzUxIzExIyQxIyQzIyQ2MiQ0NjEwMDIjNjEjJDEjJDAjJDgz

35100010

JDQ4MTYyMiM2MSMkMSMkNiMkODkkMzgxMzUxIzExIyQxIyQzIyQ3OSQyNjEwMDIjNDEjJDEjJDQjJDgz

31100864

JDQ4MTYyMiM1MSMkMSMkMCMkODkkMzgxMzUxIzExIyQxIyQzIyQxMyQyNjE4MzIjNzEjJDEjJDgjJDgz

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming-related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although hashing is not intended for use in any way like lossy compression, it does compress, and it is very lossy.  There is not only no *known* way to reverse a good hash.  There is no theoretically possible way either.

Consider the entire set of numbers 10,000 digits long.  There are 10^10000 possibilities.  All of them can be hashed into a 512 bit hash.  But a 512 bit hash has 2^512, or roughly 10^100, possibilities.  So each of those 10^100 possible hashes in the SHA512 algorithm would contain 10^100 collisions if you could hash every 10,000 digit number.

Yes, that is a whole lot of collisions.  Hash algorithms are collision resistant, but it is impossible to make one collision proof.  Don't bet you'll live long enough to see a single such collision because you probably won't.  But if you could hash every 10,000 digit number you would find lots of them.

Then the question comes.  If you have just the hash, which of those 10^100 different plain texts did it come from?  That information is not contained in the hash itself.  There is no way to go from a hash to the plain text that resulted in it.  In fact the way hash functions are built, you cannot even examine any hash or set of hashes and say with confidence the setting of a single bit of the original bytes.  If you could, we would say that hash is broken and nobody would use it any more.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to decrypt one-way encryption?

Look, the ward is not `encryption` rather it is known as *Hashing*! And the answer is, NO. You can't *decrypt* a HASH message to its plain text, means reversing is not possible for Hashing. For example,

```
SHA(plainText) -> hashText
```

then there is no mechanism like `inVerseSHA` which can do the following,

```
inVerseSHA(hashText) -> plainText
```

All you can do is generate the `hashText` again in another entity by the same procedure `SHA(plainText) -> hashText` and check the integrity of the text message (matching the two `hashText`), that is the main purpose of hashing.

I think you first read more details about [Data Integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integrity) and [Hash Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

**EDIT:**

> I don't know encrpytion method (LIKE SHA, MD5 anything else..)

`SHA`, `MD5` are not *encryption* method, the are cryptographic hash functions where `SHA-1` is most widely used , generates 160 bit values.

Comment: If I know a lot of plaintext and hashText, is it perfectly 'NO'?

Comment: A cryptographic hash function (e.g SHA or MD5) allows one to easily verify that some input data maps to a given hash value (`hashText`), but if the input data is unknown, it is **deliberately difficult** to reconstruct it (or equivalent alternatives) by knowing the stored hash value. This is used for assuring integrity of transmitted data.